# Script dependencies generates different outputs

Tags: scripts

The block of code below is supposed to generate a list of dependencies for a given `handle` e.g. `jquery`.

```
function get_deps() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $wp_scripts->all_deps( 'jquery' );
    $output = [];    // Initialize an empty array
    foreach( $wp_scripts->to_do as $handle ) {
        $dep = wp_scripts()->registered[ $handle ];
        $output [] = $dep->src;
    }
    $result = $output;
    return $result;
}
```

The `function` below is a quick test of the `get_deps` function to check if it spits out the expected list of dependencies.

```
function display_scripts() {
    print_r( get_deps() ) ;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'display_scripts',  PHP_INT_MAX );
```

This works as expected however if `print_r( get_deps() ) ;` is called with the `script_loader_tag` filter, it produces a unexpected list.

As a quick test, if I replace `jquery` with `lazysizes` which has no dependencies like so:

```
function get_deps() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $wp_scripts->all_deps( 'lazysizes' );
    $output = [];    // Initialize an empty array
    foreach( $wp_scripts->to_do as $handle ) {
        $dep = wp_scripts()->registered[ $handle ];
        $output [] = $dep->src;
    }
    $result = $output;
    return $result;
}
```

And quickly validate it with:

```
function display_scripts() {
    print_r( get_deps() ) ;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'display_scripts',  PHP_INT_MAX );
```

The output is: `Array ( )`. So far so good. Now if `print_r( get_deps() ) ;` included in a block of code with the `script_loader_tag` filter, the results are completely different. Here's the test:

```
function test() {
    print_r( get_deps() ) ;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'test', 10 );
```

which produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js
    [1] =&gt; /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js
    [2] =&gt; 
    [3] =&gt; https://domain.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/js/plugins.js
    [4] =&gt; https://domain.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/js/script.js
)
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js
    [1] =&gt; 
    [2] =&gt; https://domain.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/js/plugins.js
    [3] =&gt; https://domain.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/js/script.js
)
```

I've no idea why it does this since it should be `Array()`. What am I doing wrong or overlooking?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_scripts` and the `script_loader_tag` are two completely different WordPress functions. What is it, you are trying to achieve? what's the end goal?

Answer (score 0):

I think the for each loop is a little wonky, if I'm understanding your question, you can try the following.

```php
// Generate a list of dependencies for a given handle.
function get_deps() {
    global $wp_scripts;

    $deps = array();
    foreach ( $wp_scripts->registered as $handle => $script ) {
        if ( in_array( 'jquery', $script->deps, true ) ) {
            $deps[] = $handle;
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $deps );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

**Would output the following;**

```php
Array
(
    [0] => common
    [1] => editor
    [2] => wp-ajax-response
    [3] => wp-api-request
    [4] => heartbeat
    [5] => jquery-ui-core
    [6] => jquery-effects-core
    [7] => jquery-form
    [8] => jquery-color
    [9] => schedule
    [10] => etc...

)
```

**Edit: Added for completeness.**

```php
// Generate a list of dependencies for a given handle.
function get_deps() {
    global $wp_scripts;

    $deps = array();
    foreach ( $wp_scripts->registered as $handle => $script ) {
        if ( in_array( 'jquery-migrate', $script->deps, true ) ) {
            $deps[] = $handle;
        }
    }
    
    return $deps;
}

function foo_enqueue_scripts() {
    $the_deps = get_deps();
    
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $the_deps );
    echo '</pre>';
    
    /* output from print_r:
     * Array
     * (
     *     [0] => jquery
     * )
     */
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-foo-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/foo.js', $the_deps, '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foo_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: that's doesn't return any output.

Comment: It does for me; I'm not understanding your question. 

Comment: Are you using a particular hook to return the output?

Comment: No just the, bog standard `wp_enqueue_script()` hook. (See updated answer.)